# Will React functional component always re-renders as long as it has a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been struggling with a performance problem in a React (React Native to be exact) app for days. It boils down to this problem:

*When a `Parent` function component has another function component as the `Child`, the `Parent` will always re-renders whenever its own parent (`GrandParent`) re-renders. And this is true even if all components are memoized with `React.memo`.*

It seems to be a fundamental problem for React, because in this common situation, `HeavyParent` will always re-renders whenever `LightGrandParent` re-renders, even if neither `HeavyParent` nor `LightChild` needs re-rendering. This is obviously causing a massive performance problem for our app.

```
<LightGrandParent>
  <HeavyParent>
    <LightChild />
  </HeavyParent>
</LightGrandParent>
```

I can't believe this is how React works. Did I miss anything?

I created [a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-curie-xor53) to show what I mean.

Comment: Just the render function being called does not mean that anything actually gets reconciled again onto the screen. If your render functions are heavy, use `useMemo` or similar.

Comment: They are called [Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). They are (generally) not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: as @AKX said you should check useMemo. it will shallow compare and decide if it needs to update

Comment: Thanks @AKX. The problem with `useMemo` in our case is, we actually don't know which components are heavy, as profiling in React Native is a joke. So basically we are left with no choice but wrapping each component with `useMemo`?

Comment: It’s difficult to help without concrete context. The dev tools are generally adequate to determine components with a long render time, but packages that drill down into specific reasons for a re-render may be helpful. There’s no generic answer other than the generic React/RN optimization paths. It sounds like things were a built then performance tested rather than testing as things were added, which makes it much more difficult to pinpoint bottlenecks. Pulling out component hierarchies for testing in isolation would help.

Comment: Your don't wrap components in useMemo, it's a hook. But maybe the age-old technique of "comment out code and see if it's significantly faster now" might work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A component re-renders if its state changes, or when its parent re-renders. Re-renders on state changes are normal. The other case sometimes is problematic. In this components tree you pasted

```js
<LightGrandParent>
  <HeavyParent>
    <LightChild />
  </HeavyParent>
</LightGrandParent>
```

`LightGrandParent` consumes `HeavyParent` with `props.children`, which gives you out of the box optimization, as React won't re-renders `HeavyParent` if `LightGrandParent` re-renders because of an internal `state` change.

Now, if you wanna also control re-renders because of `LightGrandParent`'s parent re-rendering, you could use [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to memoize `HeavyParent`.

But this won't work because `HeavyParent` consumes `LightChild` as  `children`, which is a new refrence on each render, and `memo` comparing new props with previous to do caching.

Answer (score 1):

The answers @yousumar and a few other folks provided were correct. However, this also means a very surprising phenomenon demonstrated as follows:

[image]

I know many developers won't see this as a problem and will just say "hey this is how it works". But I personally think that this at least represents a shortcoming in React's fundamentals, as it violates [the principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Also React's core doc should have pointed this out so that developers like me wouldn't get burned.